# Move view in a curve/arc path while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Using the LTInfiniteScrollView, I was able to animate the growing or the circles shown in the image below using the following code:

```
- (void)updateView:(UIView *)view withProgress:(CGFloat)progress scrollDirection:(ScrollDirection)direction {
    CGFloat size = 50;
    CGPoint center = view.center;
    view.center = center;
    size = size * (1.4 - 0.5 * (fabs(progress)));
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size);
    view.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2;
    view.center = center;
}
```

[image: Current Implementation]

What I want to achieve is an arc movement effect while scrolling like the image below. I want to move the circle in the arc path. Is there a way or formula to compute the new value of Y to make the circles look like they are moving in the arc path?

[image: What I want to implement.]

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I ended up doing and for me it works very well so far:

My Storyboard setup:

[image: Storyboard Setup]

What you can see here is a normal `UIScrollView` with a `UIView` as the Content View. The Content View has a vertical `UIStackView` inside, which takes care of equally placing the images. It is also good to have a stack, because you can simply add or remove images, without having to re-constrain anything, or having outlets for every image. Instead, you can constrain only your stack view and make an outlet to your view controller and use its `arrangedSubviews` property, to iterate through your images.

As you can see, I actually have my `UIImageView` 'Profile_One' inside another `UIView`. That isn't necessary, but I'll explain using the following picture:

[image: Screenshot]

Basically I constrained the normal `UIView` to be have the same height like the `UIScrollView`, but the `UIImageView` inside, only has half its height. I did that, because when the images are moving up along a path, and the user tries to drag them back down, the touch is often outside the `UIScrollViews` bounds, not receiving the touch.

That much to the general setup. Now here's the magic:

In order for the images to be moving to wherever they want, make sure that you disable `clipsToBounds` of your `UIScrollView` and ALL its subviews.

Now I just assigned the `UIScrollViews` delegate to the `UIViewController` and override the

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    arrangeImageStack()
}
```

Here is what my `arrangeImageStack` method does:

```
func arrangeImageStack() {
    for arrangedSubview in imageStack.arrangedSubviews {
        // Subview is the UIImageViw
        let subview = arrangedSubview.subviews[0]
        // X has to be translated from the image's superview to the view controller's view
        let x = subview.superview?.convert(subview.center, to: view).x
        // Then move the center along the new Y value
        subview.center = view.convert(CGPoint(x: x!, y: getYOnCircumference(forX: x!) - scrollView.contentOffset.y), to: subview.superview)
    }
}
```

And here is the magical `getYOnCircumference(forX: CGFloat)`:

```
func getYOnCircumference(forX x : CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let converted_x = x - view.frame.width / 2
    let radius = profileImageView.frame.width
    let result = sqrt(abs(pow(radius, 2) - pow(converted_x, 2)))
    return result
}
```

Don't be confused by the `converted_x`, this is only happening because the path that I want the images to be aligned on, lies within a circle, much bigger than the view controller's view, in order to get that smooth roundness. You will have to make sure that the X value you plug into the formula, is in line with the coordinate system of your CIRCLE- NOT YOUR VIEW. Then simply get the radius of that circle and plug it all into the formula, which you can see for yourself on [this link](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordbasiccircle.html) in the section 'solving for a coordinate'.

Your `UIScrollView` will now always translate every image inside your `UIStackView` on a circular path, based on its own scroll.

I really hope this helps you, as I have been trying to find a solution to this exact same problem for months.

Best of luck!